# RethinkDB error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: rethinkdb

Hello i'm new to RethinkDB and facing issue with join query.Whenever I run my query it gives following error:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Following is my query:

```
r.db("test")
    .table("posts")
    .innerJoin(

        r.db("test")
        .table("user")
        .filter({
            "username": "super_admin"
        }),

        lambda posts,

        user: posts["user_id"] == user["id"]
    )
    .zip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run Python code in a JavaScript interpreter.

The equivalent JavaScript code might be:

```
r.db("test").table("posts").innerJoin(
  r.db("test").table("user").filter({
    "username": "super_admin"
  }),function(posts, user){
    return posts("user_id").eq(user("id"))
  }).zip()
```

As a side note, the query could be optimized by using `eqJoin` instead of `innerJoin` and perhaps also by using an index instead of a `filter`.

Answer (score -1):

Put one semicolon ; after zip();